# reading content from a cmd window via python

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to connect to an existing cmd window and read its content.

It is an arbitrary cmd window and not a child process.

Any ideas how this can be done with python?

Thanks in advance,
Omer.

Answer (score 2):

** **Note: the [original version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7567680/1) asked how to read AND write to a cmd window** **

**Writing**

You can write to an existing command window with code such as:

```
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application()

app.connect_(path= r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
dlg = app.top_window_()
dlg.TypeKeys('hello world')
```

Notes:

1. I installed the latest version of pywinauto into a Python 2.6 installation direct from the Mercurial repository with the command:

   `pip install -e hg+https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/#egg=pywinauto`
2. I would make this rather more robust than assuming the path to cmd.exe! Documentation on selecting the application is at http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/HowTo.html

**Reading**

Reading from an existing command window appears to be somewhat more difficult! Someone on the [pywinauto-users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pywinauto-users) has got it working & is offering to post a working example: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pywinauto.user/249/focus=252 I suggest you get in touch with him.

Comment: it is an arbitrary cmd window and not a child process, any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using pywinauto, pytesseract and PIL,
What all you need to do is check for the window existence using pywinauto and take its screenshot. And read the text of the image using tesseract and PIL. Like in below code sample -

```
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import time
from PIL import Image

app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'c:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /k', create_new_console=True, wait_for_idle=False)
time.sleep(3)
# grab the arbitrary window
calc = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title='c:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe')
# print the dump tree (control identifiers) of the window
calc.dump_tree()

# type command and hit enter 
calc.type_keys("dir")
calc.type_keys('{ENTER}')

# select the window for taking screenshot
textarea = calc.child_window(title='Text Area')
textarea.set_focus()
textarea.draw_outline()
img = textarea.capture_as_image()
img.save('CMD_screenshot.png')

# Read the image using tesseract
path_to_tesseract = r"C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
image_path = r"CMD_screenshot.png"
img = Image.open(image_path)
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

# Displaying the extracted text
print(text[:-1])
```

sample output - dates of the file created -

```
08/24/2022
8/11/2022
06/14/2022
7/05/2022
7/06/2022
```

you will need to install  -

```
pip install pillow
pip install pytesseract
pip install pywinauto
```